Angular 13 Upgrade - No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency
I'm upgrading an Angular application from version 9 to 13. I'm using Shakapacker 8, Rails 6.0.6.1, and Angular 13.
After updating to Angular 13, I'm getting this error when building:
ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/webcli.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.pnpm/@ngtools+webpack@13.3.11_@angular+compiler-cli@13.4.0_@angular+compiler@13.4.0_typescript@4.4_psw5ptd3rrza3n5xpobodp2hkm/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: No module factory available for dependency type: CssDependency
    at /home/me/the-app-flder/node_modules/.pnpm/@ngtools+webpack@13.3.11_@angular+compiler-cli@13.4.0_@angular+compiler@13.4.0_typescript@4.4_psw5ptd3rrza3n5xpobodp2hkm/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/loader.js:81:18
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
    at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:454:9)

This is happening for all the entrypoint app components.
I've tried using style-loader, but it didn't generate the CSS and no errors were reported. The TypeScript compilation works and the JS files are emitted. I also tried using package versions released around the same time as Angular 13, but still get the same issue.
Here is my package.json:
{
  "name": "p1tsa",
  "version": "3.5",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "packageManager": "pnpm@9.15.0+sha512.76e2379760a4328ec4415815bcd6628dee727af3779aaa4c914e3944156c4299921a89f976381ee107d41f12cfa4b66681ca9c718f0668fa0831ed4c6d8ba56c",
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.9.31"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults"  
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.4.0",
    "@babel/core": "7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "7",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "v8.x",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "13.3.11",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^11.0.0",
    "angular-plotly.js": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "8",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.4.1",
    "braces": "^2.3.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "9",
    "core-js": "3",
    "css-loader": "6.8.1",
    "d3": "^6.7.0",
    "daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "deep-extend": "^0.5.1",
    "extend": "^3.0.2",
    "fstream": "^1.0.12",
    "html-loader": "1.1.0",
    "http-proxy-agent": "^4.0.1",
    "jquery": "3.5.0",
    "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.mergewith": "^4.6.2",
    "lodash.template": "^4.5.0",
    "mem": "^4.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.6.0",
    "minimatch": "^3.1.2",
    "mixin-deep": "^1.3.2",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.46",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.1",
    "plotly.js": "^1.58.5",
    "plotly.js-dist-min": "1.58.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.14",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "sass": "1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "serialize-javascript": "^3.1.0",
    "set-value": "^2.0.1",
    "shakapacker": "8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "1.1.3",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.15.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "5",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": ">=4.4.2 <4.5",
    "webpack": "5",
    "webpack-assets-manifest": "^5.2.1",
    "webpack-merge": "5",
    "webpack-sources": "^3.2.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-static-block": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-for-of": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.25.9",
    "@types/babel__core": "7",
    "@types/d3": "^6.7.0",
    "@types/moment-duration-format": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/node": "12.12.2",
    "@types/node-forge": "^1.3.11",
    "@types/react": "16.9.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.24",
    "@types/webpack": "5",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.8",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "brotli-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000697",
    "cosmiconfig": "^8.1.0",
    "cssnano": "4.1.11",
    "exports-loader": "0.7.0",
    "extract-loader": "5.0.1",
    "html-minify-loader": "^1.4.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-import": "12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "7.1.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "shallow-clone": "^3.0.1",
    "ts-node": ">=10",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4"
  }
}

And my webpack config:
import shakapacker from 'shakapacker';
import { AngularWebpackPlugin } from '@ngtools/webpack';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
import linkerPlugin from '@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel';
import path from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import sass from 'sass';

const { generateWebpackConfig } = shakapacker;
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const webpackConfig = generateWebpackConfig();
const { resolve, plugins, module } = webpackConfig;
const extensions = [
  '.js',
  '.ts',
  '.tsx',
  '.jsx',
  '.scss',
  '.sass',
  '.css',
  '.html'
];

webpackConfig.mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.RAILS_ENV || 'production';
resolve.preferRelative = true;

Object.assign(resolve, {
  extensions: [
    ...new Set([
      ...extensions,
      ...(resolve.extensions || [])
    ])
  ],
  mainFiles: ['index'],
  // // mainFields: ['module', 'main'], // Exclude 'browser'
  fullySpecified: false,
  enforceExtension: false,
});

plugins.push(
  new AngularWebpackPlugin({
    tsconfig: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json')
  }),
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: '[name].css',
    chunkFilename: '[id].css'
  })
);

module.rules.push({
  test: /\.[jt]sx$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
});
module.rules.push({
  test: /\.[cm]?js$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      compact: false,
      plugins: [linkerPlugin],
    },
  },
})
module.rules.push({
  test: /\.m?js$/,
  include: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      compact: false
    },
  },
})

const tsJsRule = module.rules.find(r => `${r.test}` === `${/\.(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx|coffee)?(\.erb)?$/}`);

tsJsRule.test = /\.[jt]s/;
tsJsRule.use = ['@ngtools/webpack'];

export default webpackConfig;

And my shakapacker.yml:
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript

  source_entry_path: packs

  nested_entries: false

  css_extract_ignore_order_warnings: false

  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/shakapacker
  webpack_compile_output: true
  shakapacker_precompile: true


  additional_paths: []

  cache_manifest: false

  webpack_loader: 'babel'

  ensure_consistent_versioning: true

  compiler_strategy: digest

  useContentHash: false


development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true
  compiler_strategy: mtime

  dev_server:

    host: localhost
    port: 3035
    hmr: false
    inline_css: false
    client:
      overlay: true
    compress: true
    allowed_hosts: 'auto'
    pretty: true
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    static:
      watch:
        ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  compile: false

  useContentHash: true

  cache_manifest: true

Any ideas what could be causing this CssDependency error or how to resolve it? Let me know if any other details would be helpful.
